# Read the number from file

Tags: java

I have file.txt like

```
7 10 5
ADD_FLIGHT SV221 Jeddah NewYork 30 7000
ADD_FLIGHT SV223 Jeddah London 30 4000
ADD_FLIGHT SV225 Jeddah Paris 30 3500
ADD_FLIGHT SV227 Jeddah Cairo 30 2000
ADD_PASS Mohammed Ali 33 M 0555788778
ADD_PASS Sara Maghrabi 30 F 0555111111
ADD_PASS Hani Ali 20 M 0555223344
ADD_PASS Mohammed Hafeth 33 M 0555889876
ADD_PASS Ahmad Sami 44 M 0555768768
ADD_FLIGHT SV332 Jeddah Riyadh 20 500
ADD_FLIGHT SV334 Jeddah Dammam 20 600
ADD_FLIGHT SV367 Jeddah Dubai 25 2000
ADD_PASS Salwa Ali 33 F 0555765672
ADD_PASS Faisal Amri 20 M 0555111111
ADD_PASS Mona Saleem 33 F 0555222112
ADD_PASS Ali Ali 33 M 0555743344
ADD_PASS Marwa Ahmad 33 F 0555545855
```

I want read num 7 and put the number like this code

```
Fligthcod []c=new Fligthcod[7];
```

How can do that ??

Answer (score 0):

Class [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) associated with class [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) allows you to read easily this kind of file.

Example from Scanner doc:

```
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("myNumbers"));
  while (sc.hasNextLong()) {
      long aLong = sc.nextLong();
  }
```

Comment: After read 7 how can put number like this>> flight []a=new flight [the number read];

Comment: Hum... store 7 in a variable and use it `Flight[] a = new Flight[myIntVariable];` ?